# Strings.Left function in C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, string, reference

I have added a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic and a using statement but still get an error calling the Left function: eg)

```
string s = e.Row.Cells[3].Text;

e.Row.Cells[3].Text = Left(s, 10);
```

"The name 'Left' does not exist in the current context".

Also tried Strings.Left and Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left and Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Left...

Any other ways to do this in C#?

Comment: Sorry for duplicating but the search didn't bring that up. "old vb function" suggests it is no longer used - which is not true.

Comment: No, imo it suggests that it's old and - yes - should not be used anymore ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use .NET methods like `String.Substring`:

```
string firstTen = s.Substring(0, 10);
```

or `String.Remove`:

```
string firstTen = s.Remove(10);
```

Note that you should handle the case that `s` is `null` or that the input string is too short.

If you insist on [`VisualBasic.Left`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y050k1wb%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) you could fully qualify it:

```
string firstTen = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Left(s, 10);
```

Comment: Fully qualifying it didn't work - I tried that. I will try substring, thanks.

Comment: @JohnnyBizzle - Did you have a reference to the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: OP has mentioned that he has _"added a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic"_.

Comment: Hmmm.... I wonder why fully qualifying it didn't work then.  We're missing some piece of information.

Comment: Fully qualifying requires including the correct class - "Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Left(s, 10);".  VB allows omitting 'Strings' in the qualification since 'Strings' is a VB 'module' and methods within it do not require the module qualification (only VB allows this or has any concept of 'module'). (Just use 'Substring'!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the String.Substring :

```
string s = e.Row.Cells[3].Text;
e.Row.Cells[3].Text = s.Trim().Substring(0, 10);
```